# gcloud functions list command return 0 items but has active cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I have deployed one cloud function (gen2) to the GCP as a trigger as HTTP, once deployed and verified at the console it is active and able to browse the URL, but when I run the `gcloud functions list` it returns 0 items.

Does anyone have the same issue when using the `gcloud functions list`? I wonder if it could be the issue on the cloud function gen2?

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading the `gcloud`(Google Cloud SDK) to the latest 406.0.0, and running the `gcloud functions list` works.

I think before the upgrade, my `gcloud` version was 3xx something.